# Are there issues if you run a IPv6 private network with IPv4 values and an empty prefix?

Tags: networking, routing, nat, ipv6, ipv4

So i recently found out that the last 32 bits of an IPv6 can be addressed by their decimal value (not universally, busybox ping doesn't).

So your IPv4 network is 10.0.0.0/8 and your IPv6 is ::10.0.0.0/104 (but your probably want to assign it as ::a00:0/104)

So i thought that it would be great to have matching IPv4 and IPv6 values, with the idea of allowing all hosts to exit through a NAT router. It does appear to work fine but i can't test it against the internet because there is no IPv6 support in my zone.

It appears to be a valid internet prefix (which is not ideal for a local network, but i find it unlikely that it will be ever used as an internet address). It also seems that the original plans for IPv4 mapping used the empty prefix instead of the ::ffff: one.

It is ok to deploy a network using these values, or should i use the fc00:: prefix?

Comment: "_your IPv6 is ::10.0.0.0/104_" That is an invalid, deprecated, IPv4-compaitlbe IPv6 address. There are now IPv4-mapped IPv6 addresses (`::ffff:0:0/96`), but those are not actually used on a network. Neither of the IPv4 for IPv6 addressing modes can be used on the public Internet. Also, the ULA (`fc00::/7`) has some rules around it. The first half `(fc00::/8`) is reserved, but you can use the second half (`fd00::/8`) but the following 40 bits must be randomly chosen. Neither can ULA be used on the public Internet.

Comment: I know it is a deprecated ipv4 to ipv6 mapping method. What i don't know is if it is a valid IPv6 address. Everything i read seems to point to it being free and valid As far as i tested everything works as it should in local networking (as far as Linux and Windows is concerned) https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml. Well. Guess i will have to try in my personal use and see if it eats my hamster.

Comment: No. The current valid Global addresses are all in `2000::/3`. The _[IANA IPv6 Special-Purpose Address Registry](https://www.iana.org/assignments/iana-ipv6-special-registry/iana-ipv6-special-registry.xhtml)_ lists other IPv6 ranges, and if they can be used as source or destination addresses, if they are forwardable (routable), Globally Reachable, and whether or not they are Reserved-by-Protocol (IPv6 must recognize and take special action for them).